# How to build a Jupyter Notebook page to access remote Molecular Dynamics results?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter

I would like to know whether it is possible, and how, to host a Jupyter Notebook page somewhere remotely (so not on my machine) that a collaborator could load in their web browser to view results? There is no shared machine, all the files need to be in one central location e.g., hosted on Google Drive, and the Jupyter Notebook page must also be URL based accessible.

First of all, I've performed MD simulations using Gromacs and the files are currently local on my machine. I then load Jupyter Notebook on my machine, import the MDAnalysis Python package and perform some analysis that depends on those trajectory files generated by Gromacs (.trr/.xtc/.pdb). I also include some short simulation trajectories using NGLViewer so I can observe the parts of a simulation.

The problem I face is that I want my collaborator to see/interact with the analysis work and observe the simulations using NGLViewer.

There are a few challenges involved:

(1) How/where do I host a Jupyter Notebook remotely so my collaborator can view progress in a browser window? I'm not expecting them to make edits or run code, just observe and copy text and download figures. This is to save me from packaging (e.g., as a markdown document of some kind) incremental versions of analysis and emailing them over.

(2) What is required for analysis code (written in Python and using the MDAnalysis package) in this remote Jupyter Notebook page to load data files that are stored remotely on e.g., Google Drive?

(3) Similar to (2), can NGLViewer load a remote file e.g., stored on Google Drive, and display the trajectory on the site for the collaborator to observe?

Although my question ties in python packages such as MDAnalysis, NGLViewer and the results from a third party application (Gromacs), I'm looking for a new way sharing results from multiple projects to teams in different countries, along with my own team who I can't meet in person at the moment.

Comment: You can use Binder or Google Colab, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Google Drive folder and add the data to it. Then share the data with all your colleagues that need to access the data.

Finally, create a Google Colab notebook and add the code there. You can choose to allow people to edit and run the notebook or only allow them to see the results. If you only give them read permission, they will have to save a copy from the notebook into their own google drive to be allowed to edit the notebook.

These options are all available in the menu bar from Colab.

You can connect your google drive folder to Colab as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting mixed messages from colleagues. The platform must (a) have Python, (b) load additional modules inc mdanalysis and nglview/nglviewer, (c) load in fields external from it e.g., point to Google Drive (I have 2+ TB so this over github),  (d) accessed by not just the developer/researcher. Will Google Colab support this? I'm happy to do the work if I know the right 'nouns' to research/learn.

Comment: Hi Anthony, here's what I know:
(A) Ok
(B) you can install it in Colab using (!pip install nglview)
(C) This might be a bottleneck, as far as I know, Colab has a limit of around 70GB, So you will only be able to load around that from google drive. Google drive also has storage limitations, you will have to pay to be able to store +2TB
(D) also works fine

Comment: To be honest, Colab is a good and quick fix for your problem, but if you want a long term professional solution, I suggest you look into a cloud solution. Amazon AWS, Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud. They will all offer you an environment to share data and notebooks and are far better than Colab. You will need to open your budget though since they are all paid and are not cheap.

Comment: You've helped me with my question, many thanks.